# Why are dependencies not resolved with Poetry add?

Tags: python, python-poetry

I am using Poetry as a dependency manager. I installed packages using 'poetry add'. Why are some packages not being resolved and reported as missing? Am I supposed to do a bunch of other configurations first before I can use Poetry?

When I run for example poetry add tenacity I get the following message:

```
The following packages are already present in the pyproject.toml and will be skipped:

  • tenacity

If you want to update it to the latest compatible version, you can use `poetry update package`.
If you prefer to upgrade it to the latest available version, you can use `poetry add package@latest`.

Nothing to add.
```

But in my project it shows tenacity underlined with yellow (VS Code) and 'Import tenacity cannot be resolved' So what did 'poetry add' then do?
How do I fix this please?

Comment: This is a VSCode configuration problem that it needs to know where to look for the installed Python packages. See the documentation here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python#_environments. You likely need to "select the interpreter"

You can verify that tenacity was installed by running: `poetry run pip freeze`